# UARTの使用方法について

Tags: spresense, usb

Spresense本体と拡張ボードは、UARTとしては同一系統を使用する為同時に使用できないとありますが、
Spresense本体側でUARTを使用した場合、本体のUSB(CN2)及び、拡張ボードのUSB(CN6)は、使用できなくなるのでしょうか？

ELTRESアドオンボードとSpresense本体をUART接続しつつ、USBポートから外部器機とデータ通信できないかと考えております。

Comment: SPRESENSEでUART使って制御と言った場合, UART2 (UART2_TX, UART2_RX, UART2_RTS, UART2_CTS) を指すはずで USB関係ないはずです。「micro USB Type-B コネクターで Sketchなど利用するのに使う」と言った場合は (USBとしての)シリアル接続, のはず

Answer (score 0):

USBで使用できるシリアルポートはCPU本体のUARTデバイスとは無関係ですんで、独立して使用できます
SPRESENSE自体に実装されているUART端子は１系統、それに加えて、
USB経由で使用できる仮想シリアルポートは、ソフトウエアにより実装されているため、ドライバを用意すればいくらでもポートを実装できます

ってことで、

> ELTRESアドオンボードとSpresense本体をUART接続しつつ、USBポートから外部器機とデータ通信できないかと考えております

は可能です

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。